# The AAB archive has been signed with the wrong key

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, jks

I have created a Flutter application and uploaded to Google Play Console, after that I was forced to re-format my PC due to internal issues.

Now when I'm trying to upload a new version - I get the msg

(The AAB archive has been signed with the wrong key. Sign the AAB archive with the correct signing key and try again:)

I'm sure that I'm using the exact same (.jks) file as last time

So why am I getting this issue? How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have another question

It seems that the error is due to this line

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
```

Apparently I uploaded the first version with the debug key

Is there no way to fix this error and use the release key instead?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you. My situation is I create AAB for `version1` using Android Studio. But `flutter build appbundle` for `version2`. For some reason, even I use the same `.jsk` file and alias, they will generate `.aab` file with a different certificate.

I ended up use Android Studio to build the app bundle.

For this line `signingConfig signingConfigs.debug` in `build.gradle`, I keep it the same as yours.